# Does event loop changes again after async function finishes all asynchronous calls?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Let's consider this code:

```
async function testFunction() {
  // event loop 1 - before any "await", we are still in original event loop, right?
  const result = await Promise.resolve('abc');
  // event loop 2 - we have a new event loop
  return result;
}

// event loop 1
testFunction().then(result => {
  // event loop 2? Or new event loop?
})
```

**Does event loop changes again after `async` function done all asynchronous operations?** Is the event loop right before `return` statement the same as in the `then` statement?

And is there an easy way to check it?

I'm working with some synchronous API that needs to be executed in the same event loop and I want to be sure it will work.

**EDIT:**

To make it more clear, this is the real life example:

```
async function dbTransaction(tableName, transactionMode) {
  const db = await _dbPromise;
  return db.transaction([tableName], transactionMode).objectStore(tableName);
}
```

**Can I use the transaction returned by this asynchronous function?**
Some related MDN info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB#Adding_data_to_the_database

And important quote:

> Now that you have a transaction you need to understand its lifetime.
>   Transactions are tied very closely to the event loop. If you make a
>   transaction and return to the event loop without using it then the
>   transaction will become inactive.

**EDIT 2:**
One more thing - the answer is yes - the transaction is usable after `const objectStore = await dbTransaction(DB_IMAGE, DB_OP_READWRITE)`. Only if I await something else I get `TRANSACTION_INACTIVE_ERR` error - which makes sense.
So is it by design? Does it mean it is indeed in the same event loop iteration?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. There is only a single event loop. Are you asking about counting iterations of the loop? They shouldn't be remotely relevant to anything.

Comment: @Quentin I'm referring to JavaScript Event Loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: I know what the JavaScript Event Loop is. Your question still doesn't make sense. Perhaps you could rephrase your question in terms of a practical problem. [Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: there is just *one* event loop?!

Comment: @Quentin no offense but I don't think you are skilled enough to answer this question :)

Comment: @icl7126 — The question is hard to answer because it is so unclear. You should edit it to fix that.

Comment: oh right, just because he tells you that the question is unclear he is dumb? you realize that quentin is one of the top 100 SO users... ?

Comment: This is what I'm talking about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Timing

Comment: @JonasWilms no, I see person downvoting my question without understanding it first.

Comment: maybe because it can't be understood?

Comment: @icl7126 — I *think* you are trying to ask "Can I rely on the promise I am awaiting inside `testFunction` resolving before the promise returned by `testFunction` resolves and triggers the `then()` function?", but you're trying to express it in terms of a very, very low-level detail of how JS works which really doesn't matter to getting an answer to *that* question.

Comment: @Quentin This is a JavaScript low-level related question - not an easy one. I'm surprised such a experienced guy like you wouldn't understand it at all?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transaction is only valid on a given stack.
When some asynchronous work is done, i.e. the browser gets a handler to indexedDB here:

`const db = await _dbPromise;`

a new stack is created and it continues till the end of that function.
But apart from the main stack, there's also a microtask stack and on that stack go all callbacks from promises and observers. If a promise is marked as resolved while executing instructions from a given stack, it is immediately called after the main stack empties and a transaction is still available there. (You can think of stack + microtasks as one 'tick' of a loop after which javascript passes control back to the event loop that decides what to do next).

So in your example:

```js
async function testFunction() {
  // tick 1 synchronous
  const result = await Promise.resolve('abc');
  // tick 1 microtask 1 (up resolved through the execution of the stack)
  return result;
}

// tick 1
testFunction().then(result => {
  // tick 1 microtask 2 (resolved through the execution of microtask 1)
})
```

You can get some info by checking performance panel:
[image]

This video might clear what an event loop is and how it works: https://vimeo.com/254947206

Comment: Amazing explanation! Thanks a lot! Now it makes sense :)